# Heroku app id within the application environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Is it possible to retrieve the app id (app123@heroku.com) within the application environment?

I know, that I can manually set a config var, but I figured such info could be exposed by Heroku?

Comment: No you it's not possible. If you tell us what you're actually trying to do there may be a way though.

Comment: I ask the question, since the app id is constant and the name can change. So I want to write reusable code for the heroku api, where no setup (setting a config var with the app id) is required.

Comment: @jacob: how we can find the app123@heroku.com

Comment: Please check if you can help here https://stackoverflow.com/q/62796668/7302526

Answer (score 1):

If you have an add-on like SendGrid or Memcache installed, you can access the environment variables for the username of one of those add-ons. For example, if you were using Ruby, you can log into the console and output the value of ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'] or ENV['MEMCACHE_USERNAME']. It's easy to extract the app id from there. I'm not sure which other add-ons also expose that value in an environment variable but you can output the entire ENV global hash and find out what's available.

Answer (score 0):

I used Jared's solution for over a year.
Today I ran into an issue when `ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME']` was not there yet (during deployment).

Heroku recommends to set a config var for this yourself, so I set:

```
heroku config:add APP_NAME=<myappname> --app <myappname>
```

And enable [lab feature](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile) that allows you to use them during compile

```
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile -a myapp
```

And now I have my app name available here:

```
ENV["APP_NAME"] # '<myappname>'
```

So I won't run into the issue again, though I would like to get this kind of info set from Heroku instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is straight from my support ticket with Heroku:

> You cannot retrieve that value yourself. This is a value that SendGrid support requires that only Heroku support can supply to them.

So you will need to ask Heroku for it via a [support ticket](https://help.heroku.com/?t=true)

#### UPDATE

Somewhat contradictorily, I found I could access my Heroku app id by running:

```
heroku config:get SENDGRID_USERNAME
app171441466@heroku.com
```