# How can I retrieve Heroku application id?

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli

I am being asked for heroku app id (the `app123@heroku.com`) by 3rd party support. I am quite sure there was some way to do get it, but I don't see it know. It's not featured in `heroku info` even in the more verbose `--json` mode.

How can I retrieve it?

Comment: Is it Id or heroku API key?

Comment: `heroku apps:info`? `heroku domains` ? View a list of CLI commands here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands, and maybe this can help you too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104609/heroku-app-id-within-the-application-environment

Comment: @svikramjeet supposedly heroku id, nto the API ke

Comment: @askprod `heroku apps:info` displays the same output as `heroku info` (no app id), `heroku domains` displays the CNAMEd domains, but nothing about heroku id.

Comment: @almad : I am not sure if it works but it could be uuid@heroku.com so uuid is what exactly represent app I'd at the moment

Comment: @svikramjeet I am being asked for that by 3rd party support and according to them, it's not the same.

Comment: Can you confirm the service name which asked for heroku app id

Comment: I don't think it would be fair, but let's say they are well-known email-sending-as-a-service provider.

Comment: @svikramjeet SendGrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, and was informed via my support ticket that the only way to get the heroku app ID (that SendGrid uses) is to ask for it via Heroku support. Here's what Heroku support says:

> You cannot retrieve that value yourself. This is a value that SendGrid support requires that only Heroku support can supply to them.

Lodge a ticket here: https://help.heroku.com/?t=true

#### UPDATE

Turns out you can access it by running

```
heroku config:get SENDGRID_USERNAME
app171441466@heroku.com
```

Comment: Thanks! It should be noted that creating a ticket is not an option for free users and that `config:get` will not work if you are trying to _add_ the plugin.

Comment: @Almad for me [`heroku addons:create sendgrid:starter`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid#provisioning-the-add-on) followed by `heroku config:get SENDGRID_USERNAME` was enough to show the app ID, even though the sendgrid addon was not working yet (apparently SendGrid start Heroku users in a 'banned' state until they interrogate you via email to verify you're not planning anything untoward). I think that would work for you / others ? (unless you were adding the third party tool some other way?)

Comment: Unfortunately no, the second command gives an empty result to me

Answer (score 5):

If someone needs a **long App ID** (01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef):

```
curl -n https://api.heroku.com/apps/$APP_NAME \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3"
```

App ID will be in the response object under "id"

Source:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#app-info

Comment: This just gives me `{ "name": "my-app" }` - do I need to add anything else? Do you know about an update to the API? The source doesn't give me more information than you already did unfortunately.

Comment: Unlike Squirellkiller, it gave me the id and much more. Note that you can just put the actual app name instead of $APP_NAME e.g. sunrise-moon-shine

Answer (score 1):

Go to your app on the Heroku dashboards, open the dev tools, check for requests coming from particleboard.heroku.com and there you have the ID, after `/apps/...`

[image]